# Translation of "I can't eat spicy food"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How would you say "I can't eat spicy food"?

> Ich kann kein scharfes Essen essen.

It sounds strange to put two "Essen"s together. Or is it okay? What would be other ways?

Comment: Ich kann scharfe Küche nicht essen.

Comment: Why not -Ich kann keine scharfe Speise essen?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is perfectly correct, but as you say one might want to avoid it. If one does not want to search for a different word for „Essen“ or „essen“ then one can resort to

> Ich kann nichts Scharfes essen.

Comment: Yes he can! After all, he can only notice that it is spicy when he eats it. Another question is if he likes it. </nitpicking>

Comment: @ingo poor you.. "html" tags are getting parsed... instead you could use \*nitpicking* or [nitpicking]

Comment: Im mündlichen Ausdruck würde ich mir keinen Kopp machen - das merkt niemand, dass da zwei Essen in Folge stehen. Aber willst Du vielleicht scharfe Speisen speisen?

Answer (score 10):

Entirely correct. The one *Essen* is the noun and *essen* the verb. 
You could also use

> Ich vertrage kein scharfes Essen.

Answer (score 3):

*Essen essen* is perfectly correct. However, I'd translate the *can't* with *darf nicht*:

> Ich darf nichts Scharfes essen.

*Ich **vertrage** nicht* is a little bit different to *Ich **darf** nicht*:

- *Ich vertrage nicht* means **my body has a bad reaction** to spicy food.
- *Ich darf nicht* means **I am not allowed** to eat spicy food.

Both are possible translations - depending on the writer's intentions.

Comment: Except you can't use this translation in the same context as the original english; this implies you're actually _forbidden_ from eating spicy food (possibly because of religious reasons) or are literally _unable_ to (because you're maybe allergic to everything that's spicy). "vertragen" is correct in this context; it's colloquial, but it's well understood as "I dislike this to the extent of refusing to eat it".

Comment: @Cubic In the question I cannot find any context from the original poster. So we have to paint a picture of different possibilities.

Comment: One English expression for "ich vertrage scharfes Essen nicht" could be "spicy food does not agree with me".

Comment: The original English sentence might also mean "I am so sensitive to spicy taste that I can't bring myself to swallow anything". Neither of the proposed translations carries that meaning.